# How to set default value on a Symfony form embedded in another form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How does one set the default form value of a Symfony form embedded within another form that are both associated with entities?

If I try to set the street property in my PropertyLocation entity to a default value in the following example, this default value does not get shown when the form renders. I know there is a data option for each form field that I could use, but I would rather not do it this way since that overrides what is set in the entity. How can I make the form show the default value stored in the entity.

```
class PropertyType
{

     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('propertyLocation', new PropertyLocationType());
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
             array('data_class' => 'UR\AppBundle\Entity\Property'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'property';
    }
}
```

Property Location Type looks like:

```
class PropertyLocationType extends AbstractType 
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('street', 'text');
    }

   /**
    * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
    */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'UR\AppBundle\Entity\PropertyLocation'
        ));
    }

   /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'propertyLocation';
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Default values could be set in the `newAction` within your controller :

Let's say that you have a **PropertyController.php** as a controller for your Property entity

Your `newAction` will look like this :

```
public function newAction()
{
    $defaultPropertyLocation = new  PropertyLocation();
    $defaultPropertyLocation->setStreet('default value ');
    $property = new Property();
    $property->setPropertyLocation($defaultPropertyLocation);
    // now you could pass your property entity to get rendred
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($property);

    return $this->render('YourBundle:Property:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $property,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Edit** Second option : 
use `data` field

```
->add('myfield', 'text', array(
     'label' => 'Field',
     'data' => 'Default value'
))
```

AFAIK There is no third option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was hoping there would be a way where you wouldn't have to explicitly create a new PropertyLocation in the newAction. Is this possible?

Comment: That's the only way I know, After all if you did not create the `PropertyLocation` entity The framework will create it

Comment: But if I set the street property in the PropertyLocation entity class to a value, why doesn't Symfony just use that value? After all, my data_class points to that entity.

Comment: Try to set it in the construct if you don't want to explicitly create an instance

Comment: It seems that setting it in the constructor, which seems ideal to me, doesn't work. Seems like Symfony doesn't initialize the data class for the embedded form until the form is submitted, so the constructor is never called.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to set default data in your collection embedded form, only need to use prototype_data field option and set the data on the __construct method. Checkout the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#prototype-data).

Otherwise, if you wish set default data to individually embedded forms, only set the data on the __construct.

Comment: `prototype_data` only applies to form ***Collections*** (OneToMany) for use in setting the default values when prototyping of the `allow_add` form fields . EG: `Property::$locations = ArrayCollection([new PropertyLocation()])` This question relates to individually embedded forms and not Collections (OneToOne) EG: `Property:$location = new PropertyLocation()`.

Comment: ty @WillB.  i jsut changed my answer

Comment: Please read the comments of the other answer, it has already been determined that using the `__construct` approach is not called in the version of Symfony the question applies to, so the default value is not set as a result. Also for clarification I was not the one that downvoted your answer.